# Dispatch jobs TO or FOR automatic risk assessment?

Tags: software

Do I need to

> Dispatch jobs TO automatic risk assessment

or

> Dispatch jobs FOR automatic risk assessment

**UPD**

*Dispatching a job* is a correct way to say it. It's from software development :)

Comment: "for risk assessment" is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct in isolation. It only depends on what you want to say. Depending on the case it could be that what you want to say is well said by both and the only difference is in what aspect of the action you want to emphasize.

> Dispatch jobs TO automatic risk assessment.

could be

- treating *automatic risk assessment* as an entity/system, like a dedicated software framework, or a task, but the phrase is treating them as the destination of the jobs.

> Dispatch jobs FOR automatic risk assessment.

could be

- treating *automatic risk assessment* as a task. An unnamed someone/something will do the automatic risk assessment on those dispatched jobs.
- treating the *automatic risk assessment* as the intention of the dispatching of the jobs. It might not be what you specifically need to say, but potentially the dispatching of the jobs is part, or one of the steps, of the *automatic risk assessment* and the phrase is qualifying it as it being with the intention of doing the larger job of automatic risk assessment. So, *automatic risk assessment* is the purpose of the dispatching.
- treating *automatic risk assessment* as an entity, but the jobs are dispatched either on their behalf, or as a service/favor to them.

Answer (score 0):

The latter sounds better. The former only makes sense if "Automatic Risk Assessment" is the name of something (like a department) that is receiving the dispatched jobs. I assume that is not the case here.